# blender animation not updating in render mode but working in texture mode

Tags: rendering, animation, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B51VSnCzGPLfdzVLQVYtYngwWDA/view?usp=sharing

I got above blend file from tf3dm , but I find that when I try to change the animation to video I am getting a blank screen.

[image]

how to render it such that I could see the animation as a video.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the [video sequence editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/index.html)  you will find an image sequence strip. Blender will render the sequencer with higher priority than the 3d view. The images can't be found, therefore a blank frame is rendered. Disable the Sequencer to ignore the image sequence in the sequencer and to render the 3D View and the Compositing setup.

Uncheck Sequencer in the Render Settings.

[image]